# What are the minimum Nuget packages for running Entity Framework Core 3?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I would like to add Entity Framework 3 to a .Net Core (3.0) WPF desktop app. I am using VS 2019. I think the minimum packages are:

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools

And of course one for the database provider:

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

Did I get this correct? Anything in the list that is not needed? Anything missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not need Tools and Design, and Core gets installed automatically with the provider package.